# My keyboard isn't responding

Tags: 14.04

When I shut down the laptop and restarted it, the keyboard worked on the lockscreen and I typed password correctly. But when I searched for a file/ an application in the search box the keyboard didn't work. I think the problem is not with the keyboard because it worked on the lock screen well and the problem is only there when we login to computer from lockscreen. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version.
Please help me by giving your help. I am hoping for sudden response from your part....

Comment: You must've accidentally activated keyboard disable shortcut as it is a laptop. The shortcut would be like try fn+f5,f6 or anything like that?

Comment: No. l haven't done anything like that..